# Triple Ratio Problem, xyz

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x = 2y$; $3y = 2z$ then $x:y:z$ = ?

Answer is $4:2:3$.

So you get this by

$${ (x = 2y)\times3 = (3x = 6y) }$$
$${ (3y = 2z)\times2 = (6y = 4z) }$$

Therefore

$${ 3x = 6y = 4z }$$

Is the problem set answer wrong? or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are approaching it the wrong way, getting the inverse of the input data.  Once you have $3x=6y=4z$, which is correct, you need to recognize that $3x=6y$ means $x$ is twice as large as $y$, not half as large.  So $3x=6y=4z$ means the ratios are $\frac 13:\frac 16:\frac 14$ or (multiplying by $12$) $4:2:3$

Answer (score 1):

We assume $x,y,z\in\mathbb{Z^+}$. Then the first solution to $3x=6y=4z=n$ occurs at $n=LCM(3,6,4)=12$. Hence $x=4,y=2,z=3$.